# Can you pause Workflow until current item is modified by a SharePoint Designer workflow or another programmatic method?

Tags: 2013, workflow

Is it possible to pause the workflow until current item has been modified by a SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow action?

Thank You

**The real question was: How to capture the date when workflow initiator changes initial parameters of a travel request in response to a manager's Change Request and re-issue tasks for the manager?**

> *First a user1 submits a travel request to the sharepoint site. When new item is created workflow fires off and collects data from manager1. If manager1 approves or denies it very easy, but if he requests for more info, workflow needs to send email to User 1 to make changes. At this very point i need to capture the modified date when user1 makes change in the form to send notification to manager1 to re-do the tasks assigned to him.*

Answer (score 1):

You can pause until some field gets changed, yes. If the field is set to not be shown on EditForm, to some extent what you want to do is feasible.

You can update the SchemaXml of the field via Server side Object Model or Web Services and CSOM to set `<Field ... ShowInEditForm='FALSE' ... />`. Then it will only be settable via workflow or other programmatic methods such as CSOM, Server OM, and Datasheet view (in SP 2010).

Then you can use Wait for `Current Item:Hidden Field` to not equal `Workflow Variable:Previous Value of the Hidden Field`.

Comment: I totally didnt understand your second paragraph, little too technical, can you provide me some articles on that. In my case what i am trying to do is. First a user1 submits a travel request to the sharepoint site. When new item is created workflow fires off and collects data from manager1. If manager1 approves or denies it very easy, but if he requests for more info, workflow needs to send email to User 1 to make changes. At this very point i need to capture the modified date when user1 makes change in the form  to send notification to manager1 to re-do the tasks assigned to him.

Comment: So I *did* misunderstand the question, sorry. You can use the `Collect data from user` action to handle this change request. The workflow shall wait for a task to be completed with custom fields that will hold the requested bits of information. Then you can start another Task process to do the final approval or denial.

Comment: Can you suggest me any articles to do so. I also used this workflow action "Wait for Modified to not equal Current Item:Modified" do yo u thin kthat might work.

Comment: It will always be equal. Won't work. Start reading here: https://support.office.com/Article/Collect-data-from-a-user-in-a-workflow-a1758bcc-6a93-4ca9-9b55-7821b91e80f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

The initial question was misleading, so here's the answer to the situation described in comments:

> First a user1 submits a travel request to the sharepoint site. When new item is created workflow fires off and collects data from manager1. If manager1 approves or denies it very easy, but if he requests for more info, workflow needs to send email to User 1 to make changes. At this very point i need to capture the modified date when user1 makes change in the form to send notification to manager1 to re-do the tasks assigned to him.

You can use the `Collect data from user` action to handle this change request. The workflow shall wait for a task to be completed with custom fields that will hold the requested bits of information. Then you can start another Task process to do the final approval or denial.

Comment: And how do i start Task process while Collect data for user is waiting. I am using sequential workflow, the workflow wont move forward unless Collect data for user task is not completed.